# Angular 2 - How can I alert a value from @Input()

Tags: angular, typescript

I pass an object to my component using:

```
@Input() passValues;
```

Further down in that object I have a nested object called "charts".

How can I alert the key of "balance" on ngOnInit of the component. I.e.

```
ngOnInit() {
alert(passValues.charts.balance);
}
```

Doing it like the above causes errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AfterViewInit

```
input { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
```

and then in your component:

```
ngAfterViewInit () {
    alert(passValues.charts.balance);
}
```